# Export custom search engines from Chrome to Opera and keep in sync

Tags: google-chrome, opera

Here describes a method but is now broken in the latest version of Chrome. Are there any other methods that I can use to do the same? Will be even better if there's a video tutorial. Thanks!

[How can I share my Google Chrome search engine entries?](https://superuser.com/questions/280694/how-can-i-share-my-google-chrome-search-engine-entries)

Comment: It's *possible* that reverting to an old version of Chrome that supports JSON, importing the search engine list, and then updating to the latest version of Chrome would work... but how many search engines do you have? It would be far faster to just add them one at a time to the current version.

Comment: I have hundreds of them unfortunately and will require them to be in sync daily. any other workaround? ☹️