# How to delete more than one item at the same time in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome; how to select more than one

- extensions and
- search engines

at the same time so that I can delete all at the same time?

Regards
John

Answer (score 1):

I believe that deleting all themes and extensions is not a simple process.

Themes can be deleted by entering `chrome://settings/`, and under Appearance
clicking "RESET TO DEFAULT".

Extensions can only be deleted in `chrome://extensions/` one at a time.
To delete all the extensions in one go, you need to position to the folder
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`
and delete all its sub-folders. This should be done when Chrome is not running.
The first time you try it, I suggest, rather than deleting, to move them
away, just in case, until you verify that there are no ill-effects.

Comment: Resetting a browser affects all settings of a browser. Mostly I observed that unwanted extensions and search engines added automatically in Chrome. While deleting unwanted extensions and search engines, I have to delete one by one. That’s why I want to select all unwanted extensions and delete them by a single click. Same way, I want to select all unwanted search engines and delete them by a single click.

Comment: For search engines see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1141135/google-chrome-remove-all-other-search-engines).