# Stop chrome from auto searching an index

Tags: google-chrome

I am on a domain that has its own DNS server, my issue is as follows,

In chrome, I have visited the url `http://something/`, which is a valid url on our domain... The issue that I find extremely aggravating is that I can no longer preform a search for `something else`, reason being, typing `something`<kbd>space</kbd> - chome thinks that I want to search `http://something/` when in reality, I never do.

My question is, how can I disable Chrome from thinking that I want to search a specific site, instead of just treating it as a general search query.

Comment: bugger, i didn't notice that i does the same for me too :/

Comment: I actually found my workaround [here](http://superuser.com/questions/276069/google-chrome-automatically-adding-websites-to-my-list-of-search-engines). Closing my own question.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a term in the address bar, you can switch between **searching** it (which is the suggestion with the magnet at its beggining) or **browsing** there, such as *"localhost"* (which is the suggestion with the paper sheet icon).

If you mean that it makes a search inside `http://something/`, it's because it got configured as a search engine. To avoid it, you have to follow these steps:

1. Right-click the address bar, and choose `Edit Search Engines`.
2. Remove `http://something/` from your search engines, using the little cross on its right.

Comment: Doesn't work for me as i don't have **http://something/** listed in my search engines list

Comment: I added a comment to my question showing the source of my workaround. It was in doing further research that I found this option. The problem is that the next time I access `http://something/` the search engine is re-added. The workaround that I am currently using still has the custom search engine exist, however I have an obscure alias that I will never type.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like it did actually add it to the `custom search engines` list. As previously stated, simply deleting it will not work as it will just be re-added next time visiting the URL.

Comment: @MattClark i don't have `http://something` listed in my search engines list. nothing to delete

Comment: For you, is `something` a valid search target? Chrome automatically adds them `i think` when it finds a search form in the source. I could be wrong.

Comment: @MattClark I think so, just found a lot of sites just now, which I didn't manually add.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like, maybe you can solve it by manually adding it in the "Other Search Engines" box.

Comment: @MattClark my `http://something` starts with **I** http://i.stack.imgur.com/nyNcc.png

Comment: @Hewbot, does't make sense when search function is already working. this post was about bypassing it and that's why it was recommended to remove the entry from  search engines list which for me is not present there

Comment: @MattClark for me Chrome seems to bypass search engines list for most of the `somethings` i type. Quite possible its my DNS that is causing this.