# How to enable Google Chrome automatically adding websites to my list of search engines?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

Today I cleaned chrome's cache and found it lost many other search engine
, only left some.

I don't know where this other search engine gone and how them generated at first. But it is need much effort to set one by one.

I just wonder how can I get those other search engine back easily?

---

After some searching I found this [Google Chrome automatically adding websites to my list of search engines?](https://superuser.com/questions/276069/google-chrome-automatically-adding-websites-to-my-list-of-search-engines)

Looks like this is a function built-in chrome.But after I access some website used to have custom search engine, Chrome didn't add search engine for them.  none of them .

So I think it must something wrong with this function . I like this function, without it I have to add custom search engine by myself.

What should I do ?

Comment: Suddenly stopped for me too :/